# Alternative to silicone that is non insulating

Tags: material-science

we are developing a product and would like to use silicone, as it has good texture and durability, however it is an insulator. We would like heat to be able to pass through the silicone rapidly. Does anyone know of any alternatives to silicone that can conduct heat and is widely available?

Thanks

Comment: What other requirements would this material have to meet and what would the material have to do other than function as a conductor (adhesive, fastener, sealant, etc.)?

Comment: Does it have to be clear?

Comment: @J.Ari should be flexible so it can be wrapped around an object

Comment: @EricShain nope! Some color would be nice

Comment: If you do a google search on "thermally conductive silicone" there are a lot of hits.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to load the silicone with silver, copper, or aluminum oxide dust to a high volume percentage. This will furnish conduction paths for heat- however, it also renders the cured silicone less flexible and tear-resistant.

Comment: Do you know of any existing suppliers that can do this at the moment? Appreciate the help!

Comment: no but it's easy to mix your own!

Answer (score 0):

Toyochem has a product called LIOELM™ FTS series — Thermal Conductive Adhesive Sheets.

They claim it is flexible but has high thermal conductivity (maximum 10W/m･K).

https://www.toyo-chem.com/en/products/electronics/lioelm_fts.html

Comment: interesting product. It seems to be quite thin adhesive sheets and perhaps not what the OP is looking for.